# Inserting form information with php to mysql does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I have a problem inserting information into a sql database.
The user needs to answer a question and submit that.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Some title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="neg.php" method="post">
    <b>Enter a title:</b><br /><input type="text" name"title" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="I !" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The php page looks like this:

```
<?php
/* get all input*/
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","X","Y","Z") or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($connection));
$sql="INSERT INTO xyz (title)
VALUES
('$_POST[title]')";
if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
  }
echo "1 record added";
?>
```

Can anyone please help me out here? I'm really stuck, tried a million things, but simply do not see what went wrong. I also do not get an error, so I'm unsure what the problem is. Can anyone please help me out here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

OP changed `INSERT INTO dislike` to `INSERT INTO xyz` from an edit after my submitting this answer, including changing `value="I don't want to see this show ever again!"` to `value="I !"`

---

Original answer from original question:

The reason why your query is not working is because the `=` is missing in `name"title"`

Change it to `name="title"`

You should also consider using [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo).

The method you're using now, is open to [`SQL injection`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

I've made it a bit more safer for you doing it the following way:

```
<?php
/* get all input*/
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","X","Y","Z") or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($connection));

$title=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['title']);
$sql="INSERT INTO dislike (title) VALUES ('$title')";
if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
  }
echo "1 record added";
?>
```

HTML rewrite:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Dislike series</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="neg.php" method="post">
        <b>Enter a title:</b><br /><input type="text" name="title" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="I don't want to see this show ever again!" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Here are a few tutorials on [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) that you can study and try:

- [**Tutorial one**](http://webdevtuts.co.uk/simple-mysqli-tutorial/#more-41)
- [**Tutorial two**](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/PHP-5:-MySQLi-Prepared-Statements/41452)
- [**Tutorial three**](http://www.phpmysqlitutorials.com/2011/04/16/mysqli-whats-the-difference-between-standard-queries-and-prepared-statements/)

Here are a few tutorials on [PDO](http://php.net/pdo):

- [**PDO tutorial one**](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)
- [**PDO tutorial two**](http://crewow.com/PHP-PDO-to-Connect-MySQL-Database.php)
- [**PDO tutorial three**](http://www.w3resource.com/php/pdo/php-pdo.php)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with the error and your very usefully recommendations. I'll certainly consider rewriting my code :D Thanks!

Comment: I added some extra information below my answer for you. They're a few tutorials on prepared statements and PDO that are pretty good and well explained. @user3448661

Comment: You're quite welcome @user3448661 Happy to help out.